Salesforce Certification details to get Credential id and Credential URL
How to get my already acquired Salesforce certification as PDF, as the email to which the certification had been sent was corrupted to some random domain name(ie. onmicrosoft.com) and now I can't able to access that email to get my certification?
I have tried through Trailhead to check my certification, I can able to see my certification under my profile but downloading it as a PDF to the local system option is not available.
I have checked in Kryterion site there also I'm not able to get my certification as pdf. It only shows that I was certified with so and so certifications.
Is there any way to get the certification as PDF?

Check this - https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdiD4UAJ/option-to-download-salesforce-certificate-online

Thanks, but the idea is still open for consideration.

Have you opened a case with Salesforce?
